# UAC and Executing Jobs via a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, administrator

I have a custom service that executes other jobs.  Need to get it to work with UAC.

To one of the applications, I was calling, I added the manifest with the line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

When trying to call this EXE from the service, I get an error:
Failed: The requested operation requires elevation

Here's the code calling the EXE, it's very generic:

```
                        p.StartInfo.UserName = szUser
                        p.StartInfo.Domain = szDomain
                        p.StartInfo.Password = securePassword
                        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = sStartPath
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = jobExecutable
                        p.StartInfo.Arguments = jobArguments
                        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = False
                        p.Start()

                        -- MORE CODE
```

So, what action do I need to take to allow a single program to "Run as Administrator" from a non-interactive service?  Does the Windows service need it's own administrator manifest?  Would that fix the problem, or is another code change required?

Comment: Might you be better to run these executables via scheduled tasks instead?

Comment: @ADyson - no.  That's a massive infrastructure change.

Comment: is it? Sounds like setting up scheduled task, vs trying to get a an executable to run in a different privilege environment than the service which is triggering it. Just run the Exe via a scheduled task with an account which has enough permissions to make it work. Not seeing how that's a "massive" change...have you missed out some crucial detail here?

Comment: @ADyson - It's a massive change because it's a scheduler that runs these, dynamic jobs, hundreds of them dynamically based on info in the database, it's not just running one fixed executable.

Comment: Ok but it seems like this one is the only one you have an issue with? Is that correct? Can you not make an exception for this case?

Comment: @ADyson - no, lots of processes meet this criteria...i really need to know how to do this through the service...not through a task scheduler

Comment: Ok. Does the service currently run under an account which has administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes - but the manifest is not on the service.